# Creating a Release Environment in VSTS programmatically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to build a code that will programmatically create or add an environment to an existing Release definition in VSTS? I can't find a guide or documentation how to work with Release environments. There is a REST API to update a definition and its environment(s) but how can I play with that to add a new environment. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should add the environment object to the JSON request as in below link and suggest you observing the Rest API calls made when environments are added through UI and saved.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#update-a-release-definition